# Socket.IO ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, socket.io, electron

I am getting this error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

[image: error]

I have looked for this error but it seems for me that my configuration of the sockets is well and I do not think is for the warning of electron.

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var server   = require('http').Server(app);
var io    = require('socket.io')(server);

var JSONTCPSOCKET = require('json-tcp-socket');
var JSONTCPSOCKET = new JSONTCPSOCKET({tls: false});


require("./rabbit")(io, JSONTCPSOCKET);
```

```
  var socket = io('http://localhost:8000',{transports: ['websocket',
    'flashsocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling', 'polling']});
```

Any idea?

Thanks mates!!

Comment: Do you even listen on port 8000 ?

Comment: Of course, down the first snippet of code I have server.listen(8000,...)

Comment: post your client config.

Comment: You don't provide one in your server options, so it defaults to `/socket.io`. Does this match up to your socket manager config?

Comment: Yes, that is okey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake.

The file that contains the server that listen in that port is in my case server.js.

When you run it with node, the start file is server.js but when you run it with electron the start file is main.js and I was never running server.js when I executed with electron, so I was not listening in that port.